# Inverse equivalence of categories

Tags: category-theory

What is an "inverse equivalence" between two categories and how is it different from the regular equivalence notion?

My book says that two functors are an "inverse equivalence"... I thought this means they are one the inverse of the other, but isn't that a regular equivalence?

Note that the answer might be "it's the same thing, just stated in a weird way". Being kinda new to category theory I just wanted to know if such an "Inverse equivalence" notion exists. Thank you.

**edit**

Context: affine Hecke algebras, with $H_n$ being the algebra and $P_n$ being the Laurent polynomial subalgebra generated by $X_i$. Also $S_n$ is the symmetric group that acts via permutation of indexes. The sentence is

*The functors ($H_n c^\tau_n \otimes_{P_n^{S_n}}$ − ) and $c^\tau_n H_n \otimes_{H_n} −$ are inverse equivalences of categories between the category of $P_n^{S_n}$-modules that are locally nilpotent for $n_n=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^{S_n}$* (notation meaning max.ideal generated by those $x_i$) *and the $H_n$-modules that are locally nilpotent for $n_n$.*

Comment: Depending on context, it might mean a contravariant equivalence. Hard to say. Can you quote a more complete passage?

Comment: Edited. To be honest, seeing the maps that define it, it seems like a normal equivalence to me. But again, I'm really new to category theory, so I'm afraid I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Functors F and G are inverse equivalences" just means that not only do F and G have inverses, they are each other's inverses.